# google app script compare value to array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this working code:

```
function hUpdate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var hRowNum = ss.getLastRow();   

  var hNew = ss.getRange(hRowNum,3).getValue();   // value being compared

  var hCompare = ss.getRange(hRowNum-1,3).getValue();
  if (hNew == hCompare)
  {hNew = 'same';}
  else
  {hNew = 'different';}

  return hNew;
}
```

What I really want to do is compare `hNew` with all values in previous rows of the same column. I know I have to use an array but I'm stuck with the actual coding.

Comment: You might be better off just publishing the arrays you want to compare and what type comparison you are looking for in particular.  Do you want to know if they are exactly the same?  Or if one row contains x elements?  Hard to say...

Comment: What do you mean publishing the arrays? I want the values in the prior rows of the same column. I want to know if they are exactly the same as `hnew`

Comment: I mean share them here.  We have no way of knowing what you are comparing otherwise.

Comment: What does it matter? I'm just trying to compare 2 string values.